# Problema al subir un archivo FTP mediante un Asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, ftp

Tengo un problema con subir un archivo a mi servidor ftp:
El problema, no es que el archivo no se suba, o que no me puedo conectar al servidor FTP (en mi red local)... El problema es que después de conectarse, subir el archivo, la conexión al servidor (desde el usuario creado) no se cierra...
El problema esta en subir el archivo, dado que si no subo nada (simplemente me **"logeo" y "deslogueo"**) todo marcha bien.
observo que nunca llega al bloque `finally`, a menos que desde el servidor desconecte al usuario manualmente.
En conclusión el problema es que sube el archivo, pero se queda trabado ahí y nunca sale de la  conexión. ¿ alguna idea para solucionar este problema ?

**Les dejo el código**

```
private  class subirFTP extends AsyncTask<Void ,Void,Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"El programa va a subir el fichero",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        msg.show();

    }

    Toast msg;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void ... params) {
    FTPClient conftp = new FTPClient();
        try {

            conftp.connect(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.102"));
            conftp.login("usurio","clave");
            //conftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/carpeta");
            conftp.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            conftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);


            BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/storage/extSdCard/texto.txt"));//Ruta del archivo para enviar
            conftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            conftp.storeFile("texto.txt",buffer);
            conftp.enterLocalActiveMode();
            buffer.close();

        }
        catch (IOException a )
        {


        }
        finally {
            try{
                conftp.logout();
                conftp.disconnect();
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que deberias agregar `conftp.logout();` al final de `buffer.close();`

Answer (score 0):

Tu código debería quedar con esas validaciones para saber si se pudo o no conectar y si debe desconectarse al final del proceso.

```
    FTPClient conftp = null;
    try {
        conftp = new FTPClient();
        conftp.connect(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.102"));
        if(conftp.isConnected()){
           conftp.login("usurio","clave");
           //conftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/carpeta");
           conftp.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
           conftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);


           BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/storage/extSdCard/texto.txt"));//Ruta del archivo para enviar
           conftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

           conftp.storeFile("texto.txt",buffer);
           conftp.enterLocalActiveMode();
           buffer.close();
           conftp.logout();
        }
        if (conftp != null && conftp.isConnected())
            conftp.disconnect();

    }
    catch (IOException a )
    {}
```